# "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'length': object is null or undefined" in ModalPopupExtender

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, runtime, modalpopupextender

I am using C# and asp.net to do the following.

When the customer clicks the Transmit Button, I need to have a confirm popup.  When the customer presses "Ok", I need to continue with the code behind function. For this I used asp.net ModalPopupExtender. And Created 2 functions in the code behind for "OK" and "Cancel" click events. My aspx code is as follows:

```
<!-- Panel -->              


             <asp:Panel ID="pnlIssues" runat="server"  BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Outset"  BorderWidth="2" BackColor="Wheat" Width="400px"  Height="106px">                                                       


             <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
             <ContentTemplate>                            

             <asp:Button ID="btnWarning" runat="server"  Text = "Cancel" OnClick ="RefreshAfterCancel_Click" CausesValidation="false"  />
             <asp:Button ID="btnOK" runat="server" Text = "OK" OnClick="TransmitAfterOK_Click" CausesValidation="false"/>
              </ContentTemplate>
           </asp:UpdatePanel>    


            </asp:Panel>  


            <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="WarningModal" TargetControlID="dummyLink2" BehaviorID="WarningModal"  PopupControlID="pnlIssues" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled" CancelControlID="btnWarning" OkControlID = "btnOK">
             </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>

              <asp:HyperLink ID="dummyLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#" />
```

This is the code behind:

```
protected void TransmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        WarningModal.Show();     


    }

    protected void RefreshAfterCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {


            Response.Redirect("~/ManageCases.aspx?CaseID=" + GlobalData.CaseID.ToString());

        }
        catch { }
    }

    protected void TransmitAfterOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        .......}
```

But when I click the transmit button, it opens the popup and when I click "OK" it gives me the error:

"Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'length': object is null or undefined".

When I click "break" and continue, it does what its supposed to do. I don't understand why it gives the error. This error only shows up in internet explorer. It works fine in FF and Chrome. Also, I am using  RADScriptManager in my masterpage(if that helps).

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I have been trying to figure this out for two days without any luck. I have tried all the tips that were answered for this error message, but still doesn't work for me. Thank you in advance.